# Click handler is not getting called on nested span element

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap css for my layout .
Following is the html.

```
<form id="todoform">
 <div id="todo-1" class="row">
 <div  class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <input type="checkbox" id="chk-1" aria-label="..."></span>
  <input type="text" id="comment-1" class="form-control" placeholder="what is the work" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">
  <span id="remove-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried to write a function , which will get called post clicking a span element , id = remove-1. Both the function are called in the ready call back.
Following is the way i tried 
**1) By giving id directly .**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#remove-1").click(function()
         {
            console.log("clicked on image");
         });
 });
```

**2) by attaching explicit handler using "on"**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on("click",".glyphicon-remove",function()
         {
             console.log("clicked on image");

         });
  });
```

Both ways are not working . I am using chrome 49.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: No errors on console . Solution given by Rion worked for me . Looks like the click was not received at all by span element . Also i did not want to do any visible styling change as i did not want to change any appearance of the element ( like color )

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript is correct, you just need to style your span so that it has a click area, e.g.

```
.glyphicon-remove {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

Without any styling the element is hidden and so the JS can't bind to it

Answer (score 1):

Currently the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) attribute tied to your element is set to `none`, which is causing the click to not get recognized (this is from the `.form-control-feedback` class in Bootstrap).

Additionally, your [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) is a bit low and is causing your actual icon to be hidden when the `<input>` element is focused on.

Try adding the following CSS style, which should resolve the issue:

```
#remove-1 {
     z-index: 3;
     pointer-events: auto;
}
```

You can [see an example of it in action here](http://jsbin.com/hileno/1/edit?html,css,output) as well.